# Preserve 3d of child element, as its parent spins

Tags: html, css

I have an element that rotates, and inside of it I have `.pop-out-item`. This has `translateZ(500px)` on it.

When the rotating element (`.rotator--child`) spins, the `.pop-out-item` stays "attached" to the rotating `div` (see code snippet)

```css
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

.rotator {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 500px;
}

.rotator--element {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  aspect-ratio: 1/ 1;
  animation: spin 10s infinite;
}

.pop-out-item{
  width: 50px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background: orange;
  transform: translateZ(500px);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}




body{
  padding: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotator">
  <div class="rotator--element">
    <div class="pop-out-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect it to look different, something like this:

[image]

Sorry for terrible drawing.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what you want is for the orange square to move with the red one, but translated. I moved the `transform-style: preserve-3d` to the red `rotator--element` and made the `translateZ` value `50px` as it's easier to see that way. As the  [transform-style MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style) states:

> The transform-style CSS property sets whether **children** of an element are positioned in the 3D space or are flattened in the plane of the element.

```css
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

.rotator {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 500px;
}

.rotator--element {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  aspect-ratio: 1/ 1;
  animation: spin 10s infinite;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.pop-out-item{
  width: 50px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background: orange;
  transform: translateZ(50px);
  
}




body{
  padding: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotator">
  <div class="rotator--element">
    <div class="pop-out-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```